# Set current project in sbt - spark build issue

Tags: apache-spark, build, sbt, apache-spark-2.0, sbt-buildinfo

I am getting the error `Set current project to spark-parent (in build file:/C:/cygwin64/spark-current/spark-2.1.1/)` while trying to build spark.  Is there an option "-Dcurrent" or some sbt switch that I can set to facilitate this or do I need to touch a build file?  I have my environment variable at the proper location for %SPARK_HOME% so that's not the problem.  I'm also working on a windows system but am doing it with cygwin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was in the wrong direction.  I was using the sbt script incorrectly for the most part. Looking at the spark dev tools I just needed an additional parameter like "build/abt compile"